# selenium ruby find parent of element

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I get the parent element of any given element in selenium with ruby?

Let's say I have this:

```
<ul>
<li id="a"></li>
</ul>
```

and I can get the li with `driver.find_element(id: "a")`, how do I get the parent of that element that I found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you to find the parent element

```
element = driver.find_element(id: "a")
element.find_element(xpath: "./..")
```

This code will help you to verify the element html

```
p element.find_element(xpath: "./..").attribute("innerHTML")
```